# Comparing English and Non English in a string in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im developing a multi language app,
In some where i need to count English chars and Arabic Chars to decide

```
nameLabel.textAlignment = .right
```

or

```
nameLabel.textAlignment = .left
```

For example some text like this :

> بازی angry birds بسیار بازی جذابی است

need `.right` text alignment and

> Angry bird is an exciting game

need `.left` text alignment!
I want to judge this by counting English and Non English chars from server.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just go through al the characters and then count the amount of english and non-english ones. After that you can compare those counts and decide which alignment you want:

```
let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") //add whatever characters you find English
var amountOfEnglishChars = 0
var amountOfNonEnglishChars = 0

for char in string.unicodeScalars {
    if characterset.contains(char) {
        amountOfEnglishChars += 1
    }
    else {
        amountOfNonEnglishChars += 1
    }
}

nameLabel.textAlignment = amountOfEnglishChars > amountOfNonEnglishChars ? .left : .right
```

Comment: Nice to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create CharacterSet using range

```
CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."Z").union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "a"..."z"))
```